# Inconsistent MD5 hash across machines using R's digest package

Tags: r, hash, md5

I want to produce md5 hashes out of R objects (in particular, dataframes) to make sure the objects are identical across machines. I've been using R's `digest` package. However, recently I found that hashes sometimes change across machines even though there is no difference in the underlying R object.

Is there any way to force the hashes to be the same always across different machines?

**Example:**

Consider the hashes produced by the following code:

```
remove(list = ls())
library(digest)

set.seed(20210812)

n_obs <- 10^6

df <- data.frame(id = seq(1:n_obs),
                 x  = rnorm(n = n_obs, mean = 0, sd = 1))

hash_md5  <- digest(df, algo="md5")
hash_sha1 <-digest(df, algo="sha1")

df_hashes <- data.frame(algo = c("md5","sha1"),
                        hash = c(hash_md5, hash_sha1))

write.csv(df_hashes, "hashes.csv")
```

Windows 10 with R 4.0.5 produces the following `hashes.csv` file:

```
"","algo","hash"
"1","md5","13e1d2f66023716efd0eab3a6659f799"
"2","sha1","0ba77e8b088397eac969f8699d5729b49e27c275"
```

Mac 11.4 with R 4.0.5 produces:

```
"","algo","hash"
"1","md5","ebab6345464325fecd8538f948cef022"
"2","sha1","1ed794ac462bbfa3b3797a4c469f7c0464da4a46"
```

As stressed in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AwjE.png), both hashes are different.

Comment: Try to narrow it down.  You are using a compound data.frame that is relatively large (and under R 4.1.* on Linux I get yet again two different hashes which is weird).  Try with a vector, then a sequence (internal ALTREP may matter), a random vector and so on.  On _reference data_ the has signature is fine.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Actually, for small datasets the hash doesn't change across machines. When I ran the above code simulating datasets with number of observations in c(10^3, 5*10^3, 10^4, 5*10^4, 10^5, 5*10^5, 5*10^6), I only observe changes in the hashes after 10^5 (both for md5 and sha1 algorithms).

ANy thoughts? I could open an issue in https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest, or alternatively define an algorithm that uses N rows of the dataframe (where N is below this "stability limit") to test whether the objects are the same across machines.

Comment: It's probably not digest. I bet that the raw vector we get from `serialize()` may differ at those sizes.  (Which you could test "quickly" by running `saveRDS()` and seeing if the binarye files are identical.)

Comment: Thanks so much Dirk. As you suggested, using `serialize()` and `identical()` I confirmed that the raw vectors are different at those sizes across machines. It was very helpful for me to become aware of this strange behavior from R's side. 
Last question: do you know whether it's possible to circumvent the problem and do what I intended originally (i.e., use hashes to check whether dataframes are different across machines)? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well have stood behind `digest` for a really long time ... in part because it is so easy to just rely on R's `serialize()`.  Because of that I actually suspect that a) either you are doing something "wrong" (in the sense of it could be avoided) or b) there is a genuine bug so it might be best if you brought this to the r-devel list with concise reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Just to close the loop, let me tell you that I'm planning to bring this up to the r-development community shortly. I'll post back here if I find something interesting.